# iPhone Setting and UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, sdk, uilocalnotification

I am new to coding on the iPhone and I have what I hope is a simple question. I have a simple app that is using UILocalNotification. I can't manage to find a way for the app to show up in the notification setting area of the phone. And when it does show up I am not user how to retrieve this information. I was looking into registerForRemoteNotificationTypes but I am pretty sure that's for push notification...
PLEASE HELP!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure any app in there has registered for remote notifications. Local notifications are set and received by the app, therefore no need for them to be in that section.